# Resharper code indenting configuration

Tags: c#, resharper, indentation

Resharper currently formats my code to:

```cs
myField1 = expression1 +
    expression2 +
        expression4 +
            expression5 +
                expression6;

if (expression1 
        || expression2
            || expression4
                || expression5
                    || expression6
                        || expression7)
{
}
```

How do I change the behaviour to something like:

```
myField1 = expression1 +
    expression2 + expression3 +
    expression4 +
    expression5 +
    expression6;


if (expression1 
    || expression2
    || expression4
    || expression5
    || expression6
    || expression7)
{
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really have `|| expression +`? That ain't valid C#, so R# is arguably free to do what it wants with it.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe no, my bad! I forgot to remove the plus symbol as I copy-pasted the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the menu:

`Resharper -> Options...`

Go to:

`Languages -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other`

And check:

`Align Multiline Constructs -> Expression`

Answer (score 1):

Under Options-Code Editing, there is options for aligning multiline constructs. One of them are Expression, which you could enable to get the behaviour you want

Answer (score 0):

By the way, stairs-like formatting is fixed in ReSharper 7.0 EAP.